# Simple formula not working in google data studio connector?

Tags: looker-studio

I'm working on a data studio connector, and trying to do a very simple formula. I simply want divide a field by 100.

```
  {
    id: "ctr",
    dataType: "NUMBER",
    semantics: { conceptType: "METRIC", semanticType: "NUMBER" },
    formula: "$ctr / 100",
    name: "ctr",
    label: "Ctr"
  }
```

Google data studio gives an error when using it.
"Sorry, we encountered an error and were unable to complete your request."

If I remove the formula line, all works fine. What is up here?

I know I can reference another field with $myfieldid though **I want to reference the current field, in this case ‘ctr’.** It also helps me avoid extra fields in my schema I’m just using for calculation.

Anyone one run into a similar issue? Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

You are defining the field with id 'ctr' and using it's value inside the same block.

You should create a new field to use '$ctr' value and then perform your calculation over it.

At this time i don't think there's a way to reference itself on the filed definition.

What you could do is set that field as `"isHidden": true` so it doesn't appear for the user and you only use it as a parameter on another field.

Comment: Gotcha. Yeah I’ve seen that way of doing it, but seams kinda redundant to have an extra field just for calculation. Especially if the schema is larger you may end up with lots of extra fields that you don’t need. Is there way to reference the field itself?

Comment: Agree with you on the extra fields, i don't think there's a way to reference itself on the filed definition. :/

Comment: Hmmm gotcha. Seams kinda odd honestly. I could see pre processing of data to get data to a specific format very helpful.

Comment: What you could do is set that field as `"isHidden": true` so it doesn't appear for the user and you only use it as a parameter on another field.

Comment: But you would still need define that field.

Comment: Justin, please set as correct answer so it can help others.